# Debug printf hanging kernel — possible causes and solutions?

Tags: arm, kernel, freebsd, porting

There are numerous parts in kernel where putting `printf` can lead to hanging of kernel (especially at early boot). (On a side note, it comes from my experience the same situation can have place with `printk` at early stages of boot of Linux). It can have numerous reasons, but sometimes reason is not obvious. You just put `printf` in a function that there is no way it is executed more than once during boot (or at least just a few times, not hundreds of times). It could still have some timing issues?

What are the typical causes of kernel boot hanging by adding `printf` in code?

As far as it comes for solution, you can probably create your own data structure and push your "stack trace" there and then print it at some point. But finding proper point to print it could be problematic. Can there be any possible policy to apply in such problematic early stages of boot? Or we are doomed to do detailed step by step analysis every time we encounter such a problem?

Comment: Maybe your kernel provides something like the [polling mode `print_ascii`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=printascii) which doesn't require interrupts and prints immediately.  `printf` and `printk` need many facilities functioning to work.

Comment: For `printk` there is `printk_ratelimit` ( http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk/printk.c?v=4.6#L2787 )  
For `printf` - can't say without code, reason depends on how you handle I/O